# Cancel/strike out a checklist item in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

In GitLab issues, you can implement *interactive* checklists in markdown by utilizing square brackets:

```
Checklist:

  * [x] ToDo one
  * [ ] ToDo two
```

You can check items by clicking on them or by inserting an `x` into the square brackets in markdown. Is there a way to cancel an item? In other words, to mark an item as *will not be done* instead of leaving it as *TODO*?

Comment: `* [ ] ~~ToDo two~~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is the strikethrough formatting, which uses double-tildes `~~` around the text you want to strike through.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#emphasis